# Черный экран после GRUB Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: grub, ubuntu

Поставил Ubuntu Server 12.04 х64 на интеловскую мамку со встроенным атомом N2800.После экрана загрузчика GRUB появляется черный экран, а потом монитор и вовсе отключется (лампочка-индикатор становится оранжевой).В безопасном режиме тоже самое происходит после бутлогов.

Пробовал прописывать "vga=791", не помогло. Монитор 1280х1024 подключен через VGA разъем.

Подскажите, пожайлуста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте для начала нажать ctrl+alt+f4 (c f1 по f12) может что покажет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в grub где-то в свойствах загрузки указать режим nomodeset, если не ошибаюсь. Хотя ситуация странная... Можно еще попробовать подключиться к серверу удаленно по ssh, но боюсь, что по умолчанию он может быть не настроен...

Answer (score 0):

Лучше попробуй 13.04 как то по стабильней работает.